# Is it a good idea to modify yii.activeForm.js if not what is the alternative way?

Tags: javascript, yii, onclick, yii2, active-form

yii.activeForm.js helps client side validation and allow or deny form submission. Onclick, active form calls the submitForm: function() automatically.

Now,I want to change the active form button text to "processing" during validation and disable the button upon successful validation to prevent double click.

I modified ( manually included 4 lines) the yii.activeForm.js file slightly and it works well in the way i need it.

```
    submitForm: function () {

     var oldtext= $('#smartbtn').text(); // manually included
     $('#smartbtn').text('Processing...'); // manually included

        var $form = $(this),
            data = $form.data('yiiActiveForm');

        if (data.validated) {
            // Second submit's call (from validate/updateInputs)
            data.submitting = false;
            var event = $.Event(events.beforeSubmit);
            $form.trigger(event);
            if (event.result === false) {
                data.validated = false;
                submitFinalize($form);
                return false;
            }
            updateHiddenButton($form);

           $('#smartbtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');// manually included

            return true;   // continue submitting the form since validation passes
        } else {

          $('#smartbtn').text(oldtext); // manually included

            // First submit's call (from yii.js/handleAction) - execute validating
            setSubmitFinalizeDefer($form);

            if (data.settings.timer !== undefined) {
                clearTimeout(data.settings.timer);
            }
            data.submitting = true;
            methods.validate.call($form);
            return false;
        }
    },
// active form 
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary'
        ,'id'=>'smartbtn']) ?>
```

However i feel it is not a good practice to modify the file generated by composer.

Is it fine to modify the  yii.activeForm.js .?
if not how can i implement the same without touching the yii.activeForm.js .?

I also noticed that web/asset directory has some randomly named subdirectories and not same on two projects( installation).
Ex: web/assets/**e67bec0b**/yii.activeForm.js
Is it for some security purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily force your change with `event`'s of yiiActiveForm. For example in your case you can do something like this:

```
$(document).on({
  beforeValidate: function (event, messages, deferreds) {
     // Disable button or change text with find child of event variable.
  },
  afterValidate: function (event, messages, errorAttributes) {
     // Restore texts...
  }
});
```

Comment: I think it is helpful. I will try to use events. Thanks